# Get all links on html page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im working on a little hobby project. I already have written the code to get a url, download the header and return the mime type / content type.

However, the step before this is the one im stuck on  - i need to retrieve the contents of all the urls on the page based inside a tag, and in quotes i.e.

```
...
<link rel='shortcut icon' href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
...
```

Would find the favicon link.

Is there anything helpful in the .net library or is this going to have to be a case for regex?

Comment: I'm getting a weird feeling that the Html Agility Pack is the way to go...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I'd look at using the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Here's an example straight from their examples page on how to find all the links in a page:

```
 HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
 {

 }
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that if the site that you are trying to load has some gzip compression, it will throw an exception on  `hw.Load` : `"'gzip' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method`. Found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36220920/6178243)

Comment: Be careful. It's a chance to get NullReferenceException here.
```Returns:
An HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection containing a collection of nodes matching the HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.XPath query, or null if no node matched the XPath expression```

Answer (score 49):

You need to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

For example:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var linkTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("link");
var linkedPages = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                                  .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
                                  .Where(u => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u));
```

Comment: Thanks for using a comprehensive and self explanatory LINQ query!

Answer (score 18):

There isn't anything built into the BCL, but fortunately you can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to accomplish this task quite simply.

As for your specific problem, please see [Easily extracting links from a snippet of html with HtmlAgilityPack](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html):

```
private List<string> ExtractAllAHrefTags(HtmlDocument htmlSnippet)
{
    List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();

    foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
        hrefTags.Add(att.Value);
    }

    return hrefTags;
}
```

Comment: I disagree that a LINQ-based approach is simpler.  Declarative? Yes. Functional? Absolutely. Simpler? No, both solutions are equal in their simplicity.

Comment: XPath should use less memory

Comment: I would suggest that using XPath would be much less memory intensive.

Answer (score 10):

How about Regex?

```
<(a|link).*?href=(\"|')(.+?)(\"|').*?>
```

with flags `IgnoreCase` and `SingleLine`

See demo on [systemtextregularexpressions.com regex.matches](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=PChhfGxpbmspLio%2FaHJlZj0oXCJ8JykoLis%2FKShcInwnKS4qPz4%3D&t=PGxpbmsgcmVsPSJzaG9ydGN1dCBpY29uIiBocmVmPSIvL2Nkbi5zc3RhdGljLm5ldC9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93L2ltZy9mYXZpY29uLmljbz92PTZjZDYwODllZTdmNiI%2BDQo8bGluayByZWw9ImFwcGxlLXRvdWNoLWljb24gaW1hZ2Vfc3JjIiBocmVmPSIvL2Nkbi5zc3RhdGljLm5ldC9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93L2ltZy9hcHBsZS10b3VjaC1pY29uLnBuZz92PTQxZjZlMTNhZGU2OSI%2BDQo8bGluayByZWw9InNlYXJjaCIgdHlwZT0iYXBwbGljYXRpb24vb3BlbnNlYXJjaGRlc2NyaXB0aW9uK3htbCIgdGl0bGU9IlN0YWNrIE92ZXJmbG93IiBocmVmPSIvb3BlbnNlYXJjaC54bWwiPg0KPGgzPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20iPmN1cnJlbnQgY29tbXVuaXR5PC9hPjwvaDM%2B)

Comment: This is a better solution than resorting to an entire 3rd party library.