# To search for strings with in a string (search for all hrefs in HTML source)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string variable that contains the entire HTML of a web page.
The web page would contain links to other websites. I would like to create a list of all hrefs (webcrawler like ).
What is the best possible way to do it ?
Will using any extension function help ? what about using Regex ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DOM parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse your document and find all links.

There's a good question on SO about how to use HTML Agility Pack available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack). Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
string html = "your HTML here";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(html);

var links = doc.DocumentNodes.DescendantNodes()
   .Where(n => n.Name == "a" && n.Attributes.Contains("href")
   .Select(n => n.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Comment: @ Donut : Thanks for enlightening me about HTML Agility Pack..I had never used it before. Iam now exploring it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find this answers your question to a T

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9e807fx.aspx

:)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Regex.

```
        Regex exp = new Regex(
            @"{href=}*{>}",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string InputText; //supply with HTTP
        MatchCollection MatchList = exp.Matches(InputText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex (should work):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches (html, @"href=""(.+?)""");
```

You can go through the matches and extract the captured URL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using HTMLAGILITYPACK? http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

With this you can simply us XPATH to get all of the links on the page and put them into a list.

```
private List<string> ExtractAllAHrefTags(HtmlDocument htmlSnippet)
{
    List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();

    foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
        hrefTags.Add(att.Value);
    }

    return hrefTags;
}
```

Taken from another post here - [Get all links on html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411/get-all-links-on-html-page)

Comment: Thanks ..I havnt looked into HTMLAGILITYPACK before..But Iam now