# Get values from html

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I am not very good at regex.
So here is my question: How can I get all the links between 
`<td><a href="` and `">`?

```
<td><a href="link">
```

Comment: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/932418

Comment: It is better solutions to use HtmlAgilityPack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: also see .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411/get-all-links-on-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"<td><a href=""link"">");

var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
            .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) for parsing HTML files:

Once you are using the DLL you can fetch the value
using code like that:

```
linkNode.Attributes["href"]
```