# Trying to download all URL's in html

Tags: c#-4.0

Can anybody help me with this code? 
I am trying to download all the URL's in this html http://mises.org/books/ (they are all pdf's )

I understand the basic logic, I think I just am messing up the regular expression. This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 

namespace DownloadPdfs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("http://mises.org/books/");

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
                request.GetResponse();

            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;

            do
            {
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                if (count != 0)
                {
                    tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

            string html = sb.ToString();
            List<string> listoflinks = new List<string>(); 

            string input = html; 
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<="")[^""]+(?="")|[^\s""]\S*");
            for (Match match = rx.Match(input); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
            {
                listoflinks.Add(match.ToString()); 
            }

            foreach (var v in listoflinks)
            {
                using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
                {
                    Client.DownloadFile(v,v);
                }
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I suggest you use the HTML Agility Pack instead http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ please? It will make it much easier to locate the links in the original HTML document. The first example here shows you how to retrieve all links: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: And if you are using html agility pack, have a look at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411/get-all-links-on-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. The pattern will match the value of `HREF` attribute for anchors.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"href=""(?<Url>[^.""]+\.pdf)""",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
for (Match match = rx.Match(input); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
{
    var link = match.Groups["Url"].Value;
    listoflinks.Add(link); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a library to parse html like HtmlAgilityPack.

```
public List<string> GetLinks(string html)
{
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var linkNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

    if (linkNodes == null)
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    var linkNodesWithLink = linkNodes.Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href")).ToList();

    var links = linkNodesWithLink.Select(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .ToList();
    links = links.Distinct().ToList();
    return links;
}
```