# Get list of the pages from website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want the logic to get all page URLs from a website if I provide a website URL, means if I will provide a website URL then I should get all the pages with URLs in a collection. How can I implement this using C#.

Comment: This is very broad and you've shown no effort towards solving your problem

Comment: Looks like related or similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411

Answer (score 2):

While this is not a trivial task, you best start with the [**Html Agility Pack**](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

It allows you to search for HTML  tags, even if the markup is invalid. It is by far superior than parsing your responses manually.

As [Save](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266522/save) noted, the following answer provides a great example:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{

}
```

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248422/548020*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.yahoo.com");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```