# How to get link HTML in C#?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following code:

```
<div id="list">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>STT</th>
      <th>Link</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Line 1</td>
      <td><a href="http://website.com/link1">Link 1</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Line 2</td>
      <td><a href="http://website.com/link2">Link 2</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I get:

http://website.com/link1

http://website.com/link2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411/get-all-links-on-html-page

Comment: Seems like you're trying to parse XML..

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath to get the `href`s of `a` elements in the table in the exact structure you've given:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='list']/table/tr[td]/td[a]/a");
```

And then scrape out all of the `@href` Attributes.

Unpacked:

> Find the div with attribute `id` with value of 'list', then navigate into child `table` , then just those `tr` rows with a `td` child, then, similarly, to the `td` elements with an `a` child.

Comment: but how do we get the results.
http://website.com/link1
http://website.com/link2

Comment: You will need to brush up on your `Xml (XmlDocument or Linq to Xml XDocument)` skills - examples of [both here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2248425/314291)

Comment: How can I get the results in the above code.