# Can't download HTML data from https URL using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, https, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have a "small" problem htmlagilitypack(HAP). When I tried to get data from a website I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: 'gzip' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation
> for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

I'm using this piece of code to get the data from the website:

```
HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
var url = "https://kat.cr/";
var data = page.Load(url);
```

After this code i get that error. I tried everything from the google but nothing helped.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HtmlWeb` doesn't support downloading from https. So instead, you can use `WebClient` with [a bit of modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata) to automatically decompress `GZip` :

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Then use `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml()` to populate your `HtmlDocument` instance from HTML string :

```
var url = "https://kat.cr/";
var data = new MyWebClient().DownloadString(url);
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, worked.
Now I have one more question, I have something like this:
`//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron11227701\"]/td/div/div/a
//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron11227702\"]/td/div/div/a
//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron11227731\"]/td/div/div/a
//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron11227755\"]/td/div/div/a
//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron11227766\"]/td/div/div/a
//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron112277771\"]/td/div/div/a`

It's there any command to get the XPATH:

`//*[@id=\"torrent_age_of_ultron(like a regex here)\"]/td/div/div/a`

Comment: @ValentinPifu XPath 1.0 which HtmlAgilityPack uses under the hood doesn't support regex. Maybe XPath `starts-with()` function is enough? Anyway, that is an entirely different topic from the original question. So, I'd suggest to post another question for that if you can't find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can intercept the request when using `HtmlWeb` to modify it based on your requirements.

```
var page = new HtmlWeb()
{
  PreRequest = request =>
  {
    // Make any changes to the request object that will be used.
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    return true;
  }
};

var url = "https://kat.cr/";
var data = page.Load(url);
```