# How to write a regular expression in c# to match internal links to articles in Wikipedia?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a regular expression that scan the html code (the string) of an article in Wikipedia for links to other articles in Wikipedia.

The links usually look like these for example:

`<a href="/wiki/English Language" title="English Language">English</a>`

```
<a href="/wiki/Spanish Language" title="Spanish Language">Spanish</a>
```

I tried the regular expression: `"<a.*href=(\"|')(.+?)(\"|')*wiki.*>"`
it works, but it also matches links to images and not just articles.

Comment: 1. What have you tried doing? 2. *Why* would you want to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31805829/

Comment: I would check for `starts with <a ` and the `href` does not contain `://`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you all, for the answers. I added the regular expression that i tried, it works, but it also find images, i don't know how to change it that it will match only articles.

Comment: you can add a restriction in the regex to filter out the images, something similat to `<a [^>]*href=['"](?!http)[^'"]+['"]`. Changing the `http` with the images types.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed. I wrote a regular expression for the beginning of the link:

```
(@"<a href=""/wiki/[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9\-\-_]+""")
```